# Serilog forward logs From Unity (or any app) to Elasticsearch instance via ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, logging, serilog

I want to send logs from the Unity app to Elasticsearch. However Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch seems complicated (if even possible) to run inside unity. The possible solution is to have an ASP.NET Web API service that can retrieve logs from the app and log them further to Elasticsearch.

**I could have Serilog.Sinks.Http in Unity application and Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch in Web API.** Is it a good solution?

**Or maybe simply send it without a logger? Right from the object I'm receiving.** Are there special features inside Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch?

There must be flexible fields, no need to define the DTO on the server side.
What could you recommend?

Comment: I've tested the solution with Serilog.Sinks.Http seems working, not a big difference from the direct solution. If there will be no answers I'll add this solution as an answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried to copy-paste settings for Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch from my ASP.NET API app into a Unity script, but unfortunately, it didn't work. Don't know why. Would you mind sharing your solution with HTTP sink?

Comment: @IlliaRatkevych I added an answer, I hope it can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to have a web server for forwarding logs to Elasticsearch.
Then you need an ASP.NET core application with such a controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LogController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<LogController> _logger;
    readonly ElasticClient _client;
    private readonly string _indexFormat;

    public LogController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<LogController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _indexFormat = configuration["LogForwarder:Elasticsearch:IndexFormat"];
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(configuration["LogForwarder:Elasticsearch:Endpoint"]))
            .BasicAuthentication(configuration["LogForwarder:Elasticsearch:Username"], configuration["LogForwarder:Elasticsearch:Password"]);

        _client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] JsonElement[] logs)
    {
        try
        {
            var logEntries = logs.Select(log => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogEntry>(log.ToString())).ToList();

            foreach (var g in logEntries.GroupBy(s => s.TimeStamp.Date))
            {
                string indexName = string.Format(_indexFormat, g.Key);
                var indexExistsResponse = _client.Indices.Exists(indexName);
                if (!indexExistsResponse.Exists)
                {
                    var createIndexResponse = _client.Indices.Create(indexName, c => c
                                                                         .Map<LogEntry>(m => m
                                                                                            .AutoMap()));

                    if (!createIndexResponse.IsValid)
                        _logger.LogError("Failed to create index {IndexName} with error {Error}", indexName, createIndexResponse.ServerError.Error);
                }

                var resp = _client.IndexMany(g, indexName);
                if (!resp.IsValid)
                    _logger.LogError("Failed to index logs with error {ServerError}", resp.ServerError?.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to process logs");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Quite dirty, stuff might be in DI instead of created in the constructor.
Also, I deserialize it in quite a tricky way with two serializers, because of the HTTP sink format. Feel free to edit this answer if you have a better solution.

then in Unity, somewhere in your code:

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                 .WriteTo.Unity3D() // https://github.com/KuraiAndras/Serilog.Sinks.Unity3D
                 .WriteTo.Http(requestUri: "https://my-logging-endpoint.com/Log", period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), queueLimitBytes: 10_000_000)
                 .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was trying to troubleshoot the same problem - write logs from a Unity project to a remote Elasticsearch instance, I discovered the following exception:

```
Caught exception while preforming bulk operation to Elasticsearch: Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: The method or operation is not implemented. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Net.Http.MonoWebRequestHandler.set_MaxConnectionsPerServer (System.Int32 value) [0x00000] in <9ba5951f23f145c3931879cd4bb7f4ef>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_MaxConnectionsPerServer (System.Int32 value) [0x00000] in <9ba5951f23f145c3931879cd4bb7f4ef>:0 
  at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.CreateHttpClientHandler (Elasticsearch.Net.RequestData requestData) [0x00032] in <0cc67541a10c4390b1929b79f0246c2a>:0 
  at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.<.ctor>b__12_0 (Elasticsearch.Net.RequestData r) [0x00000] in <0cc67541a10c4390b1929b79f0246c2a>:0 
  at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestDataHttpClientFactory.CreateHandlerEntry (System.Int32 key, Elasticsearch.Net.RequestData requestData) [0x00000] in <0cc67541a10c4390b1929b79f0246c2a>:0 
  at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestDataHttpClientFactory+<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<.ctor>b__1 () [0x00000] in <0cc67541a10c4390b1929b79f0246c2a>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [0x0001c] in <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

(I got this exception by putting `SelfLog.Enable(Debug.Log);` before creating an instance of the logger. See details in the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics)).

This made me think that this sink might not work on Mono runtime.

But then I found [this thread](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/issues/134). Setting the connection limit to `-1` fixed the problem, and logs started appearing in Elasticsearch. However, I don't know the downside of this solution and how this will affect the end users. Particularly, I am concerned about the battery drain on the mobile device due to the bigger amount of HTTP connections. There is another solution described in that thread, but I didn't test it yet.

---

The final solution I used:

```
SelfLog.Enable(Debug.Log);

ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
    new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("https://my.domain.com"))
    {
      ModifyConnectionSettings = settings => settings.ConnectionLimit(-1), // this line fixed the problem
      EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog,
    })
  .CreateLogger();

logger.Information("test");
```

Comment: How did you add the Elastcsearch library to Unity? It has quite a lot of dependencies and some are not compatible with Il2cpp